# Where do I run dbcc checkdb?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was told to run dbcc checkdb on a Microsoft SQL server database.  Exactly where am I supposed to run this?  In the SQL Server Configuration Manager?  If so, where do I actually type this command?

Answer (score 3):

In management studio click new query and type:

```
Use [Your database name]
DBCC CheckDB
```

Answer (score 2):

No you type is into a command or query shell. You can open one using [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) shell if you have the SQL server client components installed. Also you can use the [SQL Server Management Studio.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)